# Error in getting the value from the database table

Tags: sql, database, syntax, group-by

I've sorted out people who got full score for the challenge of different difficulty level. However, the question states that query hacker_id and name of the people who got full score for more than once. I'm encountering a problem with COUNT. I tried to count the frequency of the name appearing in the table, but it wouldn't allow me to. I suspect there is something wrong with the GROUPBY syntax. Could anybody help me?

**Previous Code**

```
Select s.challenge_id,s.hacker_id,h.name,s.submission_id,c.difficulty_level,s.score
FROM (((Hackers AS h JOIN Submission AS s ON h.hacker_id=s.hacker_id)JOIN Challenges AS c ON c.challenge_id=s.challenge_id)JOIN Difficulty AS d ON d.difficulty_level=c.difficulty_level)
WHERE c.difficulty_level=d.difficulty_level and s.score=d.score
```

**Result**

```
 challenge_id | hacker_id | name |submission_id |difficulty_level |score

    71055        86870      Todd     94613                 2    30
    66730        90411      Joe      97397                 6    100
    71055        90411      Joe      97431                 2    30
```

**Problem**

```
 Select g.hacker_id,g.name,COUNT(g.name)
 FROM (Select s.challenge_id,s.hacker_id,h.name,s.submission_id,c.difficulty_level,s.score
 FROM (((Hackers AS h JOIN Submission AS s ON h.hacker_id=s.hacker_id)JOIN Challenges AS c ON c.challenge_id=s.challenge_id)JOIN Difficulty AS d ON d.difficulty_level=c.difficulty_level)
 WHERE c.difficulty_level=d.difficulty_level and s.score=d.score) AS g
 WHERE COUNT(g.name)>1
 GROUBY g.hacker_id,g.name;
```

Comment: share your expected output and sample data and your dbms name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need `COUNT` of each name that appeared more than once in your first query then you can use the following

```
SELECT hacker_id, name, COUNT(name)
FROM
(
Select s.challenge_id,s.hacker_id,h.name,s.submission_id,c.difficulty_level,s.score
FROM (((Hackers AS h JOIN Submission AS s ON h.hacker_id=s.hacker_id)JOIN Challenges AS c ON c.challenge_id=s.challenge_id)JOIN Difficulty AS d ON d.difficulty_level=c.difficulty_level)
WHERE c.difficulty_level=d.difficulty_level and s.score=d.score
) AS T
GROUP BY hacker_id, name
HAVING COUNT(name) > 1
```

`HAVING` is used to filter the aggregated result